# extract 2 column rages from TXT; insert comma delimiter; save as CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a .txt file that does not have delimiters. I want to extract 2 column ranges from the file, and separate them by a comma delimiter. i then want to save the resulting data as a CSV.

For example, here is a 'raw' string:

```
abcdefghij
```

I want the script to convert it to this:

```
abc,h
```

I know GC / SC; I just need to know how to do the string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your columns are delimited by a start and end index, you could do something like this:

```
get-content raw.txt | %{ "$($_[$0..2] -join ''),$($_[7..7]  -join '')"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the -replace operator:

```
$text = 'abcdefghij'
$text -replace '(.{3}).{4}(.).+','$1,$2'

abc,h
```

Comment: This is nifty, but it looks like hell. :)

Comment: There was an explosion at a punctuation factory.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, this looks like fun.

How about:

```
"abcdefghij" | %{$_.Remove(3), $_[7] -join ","}
```

I think it would be more helpful to see the actual data you're trying to extract from.  There are dozens of ways to do string manipulation and your choice is going to depend heavily on what it is you're trying to extract.